# Can't enable a file in Version Control RCS in Emacs 26

Tags: init-file, vc, load-path

Trying here to set a file with VC RCS, but I'm having some trouble finding the `.el` file and enable it.

Already managed to download `rcs.el` from [this link](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/lcb/newlisp/rcs.el), but it isn't being recognized in Emacs.

Already copied it into `~/.emacs.d/lisp/` and added following info in `.emacs` file:

```el
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")
(load "rcs")
```

It just returns me the error message `Searching for program: No such file or directory, rcs`, despite having tried to enable it via `Ctrl + x v v` command.

Comment: It sounds like you need to install [rcs](https://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/rcs.html) the command line program, not the Emacs package.

Comment: Looks like that it was really this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the error message `Searching for program: No such file or directory, rcs,`

This means Emacs can't find the executable called `rcs`.  You need to install it through your OS package manager, or build it from source: https://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/rcs.html

You don't need the `rcs.el` package, as Emacs' builtin `vc-rcs` will already handle it.

Comment: I'm just using it now!

Would you know how could I revert to a previous not immediately version of the file?

For example, I'm writing on version 1.7 and want to revert do version 1.2 instead of 1.6.

Comment: @Vasconcelos1914 I've never used `rcs` myself, but maybe `C-x v u` (`vc-revert`) would help?

Comment: This commands reverts to the immediately previous version, I'd like to revert to some further previous, like from 1.8 to 1.5, instead of only 1.8 to 1.7!

Comment: Just managed on how to do it!

One should `C - x v g` (`vc-annotate`), move to previous or next revision entry with `p` or `n`, and then `f` to visit the desired version!

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, if you are going to use RCS, I would highly recommend src: http://www.catb.org/~esr/src/
It does everything that RCS does and more, and Emacs supports it as well (or at least recent versions of Emacs do).